# Conditional Formatting on Google Sheets with Named Ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I've searched a bit for this issue and maybe I can get help here.
I'm trying to apply a conditional formatting through a named range and I only figured out that "Indirect" plays an huge role on this.

This is the typical table I'm working on, Heading, plus every row has a name with some notes. The table has a named range (Let's call it "Table") assigned to A1:D7 because I have some scripts on GAS that sort the list in different ways based on button pressing.

Since the table is updated pretty often, I just add rows to the "Table" Named range, so the script works fine.

[image]

Under the table the typical conditional formatting I use to color the zero or negative cells of both the column B and C but not the column D

[image]

Now what I have to do is to apply the whole conditional formatting on only the named range (but just the columns B and C).
I could "Apply to the range" B:C (So I don't have to change it) but under the table there are some other numeric data that I don't want to format.

Using a custom formula `=INDIRECT("Table")<=0`
doesn't work either since the table has the column Name, plus with some arrangements it colors both the cells B* and C* if the B value is negative and the C is not.

I'll probably add some more stuff since I'm working on it but if someone could aid just on this it would be very helpful

Comment: Just to clarify to better understand your goal, is this [sample image](https://imgur.com/a/OUXTMl1) is what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes pretty much, the numbers in the 2nd red box shouldn't be highlighted, I found something and I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Browsing a bit and understanding that the Conditional formatting just cycle every cell in the range applied and uses the custom formula to check if it should format it or not, I should put it the fact that the cell has to be inside the named range as a condition.

I found this to be useful on a "B2:C" range `=AND(NOT(ISERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("Table"),ROW(B2),COLUMN(B2)))),*condition1_on_B2*,*condition2_on_B2*,*etc*)`

(found it on the second post [here on this link](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/determine-if-cell-is-contained-within-named-range-no-vba.651983/))

The first conditions returns true when the cell is not inside the named range

- `NOT` to reverse the `ISERROR` value
- `ISERROR` will return true if `INDEX` throws an error which is only when the cell is outside the named range
- `INDEX` will attempt to find the cell B2 (or the cell the conditional formatting is checking on every iteration) inside the named range.

It probably is very heavy, performance-wise but for now it works, if there is something else, I'll wait for a better answer.